# How to remotely control a userscript using tampermonkey? To enable/disable the script for other users if something happens (in case i want to change.)

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey, userscripts

All I want to do is make my code publicly unavailable. And in case I need to make changes to the script, do it remotely so as not to disturb other users.

I wanted to do it using this guy's work, but it didn't work out for me.

https://github.com/mast4461/tampermonkey-remote-script-loader

Also, I saw a similar discussion on the stack:

[How to remotely Enable/Disable a tampermonkey script for other users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61244780/how-to-remotely-enable-disable-a-tampermonkey-script-for-other-users)
with a solution like this:

```
    fetch('serverEndpoint')
      .then(res => res.text())
      .then((text) => {
        eval(text);
      });
```

Does anyone have any thoughts on this? I would be grateful for any advice.

Comment: Any script you're fetching can be loaded by any user, so what's the point in obscuring the actual script? I know I certainly wouldn't trust a userscript, when all it does is `eval` an externally loaded script... That just looks like you're trying to hide something malicious.

Comment: It may look really suspicious, but I'll explain in more detail:
I am making a script for a browser game that renders a few extra buttons. The essence of the script is that it refers to classes that inside the game can change with each update. Therefore, I want to make sure that with each update of the classes in the game, I make changes to the script (change the name of the classes) and everything works the same as before.

Answer (score 0):

> All I want to do is make my code publicly unavailable.

While it is possible to minify, obfuscate or hide code remotely, all such attempts will be seen as attempt to inject malware and the userscript will be marked as such.

Userscript-s code by default should be accessible.

> And in case I need to make changes to the script, do it remotely so as not to disturb other users.

All userscript managers support update & auto-update so once you update the script, userscript manager will update the user's version.

Userscripts are loaded per page. Making XHR requests to a remote server every time a page loads adds considerable (and often needless) load to the page, extension & browser.