# How to disable my TamperMonkey Userscript for others

Tags: javascript, typescript, fetch, tampermonkey

How can I disable my Tampermonkey userscript for other users?
I have looked at similar posts; such as these
[How to remotely Enable/Disable a tampermonkey script for other users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61244780/how-to-remotely-enable-disable-a-tampermonkey-script-for-other-users)

But none of them has worked for me.
On the post that I saw, it says I can use fetch to update/disable my scripts for other users in Tampermonkey. However. I am not sure how to actually use this. Do I just apply the code below in my script?

```
fetch('serverEndpoint')
  .then(res => res.text())
  .then((text) => {
    eval(text);
  });
```

Comment: Your question isn't clear to me. Do you mean that you've posted the source code of a userscript publicly, and some people have installed it, and now you want to make the script stop working for others?

Comment: Yep, I want to also be able to update the code as well if that's possible.

Comment: "Does anyone know a backdoor to let me delete stuff in other people's browsers?"

Answer (score 0):

Automatically and remotely disabling others' installations of your userscript would only be possible if the script you *originally published* uses the technique described in the linked question if it fetches the JavaScript to execute from a remote server. To break the userscript, you would then just overwrite your `serverEndpoint` with a blank file, or something of the sort, so that the response text doesn't contain any of the code to execute.

If you included a `@downloadURL` in the original userscript, or the original userscript was installable via a *link* (rather than copying and pasting the code in), and you control that URL, it would be *possible* to put a new file there with an updated version but without the original code, and to hope that some of the users of the userscript would try to update their scripts every so often, and to hope that they miss the fact that the new script doesn't actually contain the same logic as your original script. But that's a stretch.

Generally, if the source code is already out there, especially if it's on a site you don't control, it's difficult to impossible to put it back in the box. And you can't take control of other users' computers and forcibly uninstall your script from their machine. The only surefire way to keep others from being able to do something with your code is to make sure they never have access to it in the first place - and it sounds like it's too late for that.